# How to update a table on one database from data of another table in another database in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am handling two online stores using **different databases with exact same table names**.
Both are identical databases in structure.
What I need to do is to connect these two databases.

**products are adding separately to two stores**.
I need to add some products to `store2` from `store1` by selecting (like adding a button to go to store2 table).

When I click a product in `store1` to goto `store2` I like to create function to run in my store1 copying **all the table values to insert into store2 database table**.
Is this possible? can you guide me to how to write mysql to implement thing like this.

**(I am only asking for how to write the mysql part)**

Thanks in Adavnce

Comment: You can do it in a simple way At the time of insertion in db1(store1) write insert query for db2(store2) repeat the same procedure while adding product in store2

Comment: @JustCode Problem is I want to select which one to go to store2 after creating products in Store1. Its like all the product are available in store1 and some of them need to display in store2.And also store2 has its own product which is not in store1. Thanks for quick response

Comment: it's possible on click you can write a function connect to 2nd db and insert that product into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as both databases are on the same server, you should be able to access tables form each database by fully qualifying the database name.

To copy rows (products) from `store1` to `store2`, the query would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO store2.product_table
SELECT * FROM store1.product_table
WHERE store1.product_table.id = 1;
```

Comment: Wow that's cool. I have a question for you. If I am going to add this to my store1 function, do I need to create a connection to store2 database as well? or is it okay I only use store1 database conncetion

Comment: If you are wanting to do this with PHP, you will need to create two MySQLi/PDO database connection objects (assuming your are using one of those) - one for each database. Then use those individual database connections to Select/Update and manipulate the data as needed. My answer is unfortunately not going to help you with this but if you open a new question based on a PHP solution with your code, I could help.

Comment: Thanks man. I cleared my doubts because of your answer. So I am able to solve my problem. Thanks alot again.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using federated mysql if you want to transparently copy data from one table in one server to another table in another server.

Another solution is to use an Extract Transform and Load (ETL) software.

You can also possibly have your php script connect to both databases and handle the following cases:

- In db1 and not in db2
- In db2 and not in db1
- In both db1 and db2

In the last case, you might have to check if the two records are different and decide which one should overwrite the other.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try and let you know.